# Graphics card possible power issue

Tags: installation, power-supply, hardware-failure, gpu

I had an nVidia GTS 8800 that stopped working suddenly.  I thought the card had just died so I purchased a Sapphire Dual-X R9 280X 3GB GDDR5 card to replace it.  The new card does not work either.

Both cards have 6-pin power connectors to the PSU, so I so I tried a friend's card that doesn't and it works fine.

The fans on the card are running, but the screen is black.  I checked both six pin wires from the PSU both seem to be giving out power.

PSU is a 910-watt Silencer capable of running the card.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just because the PSU is 900W does not rule out one of the 12v lines burning out.

You've pretty much established that the rest of the system is fine with a low power card and the likelihood of a new card having the exact same problem as the old card is very slim.

It sounds quite likely that one (or both) of the dedicated graphics card power supply lines in your power supply is dead. They are special high power outputs and will be independent of the motherboard and lower power outputs, especially so on a higher output PSU. It is also entirely possible that it was your old graphics card dying that destroyed the power output on the PSU.

Your next best bet is to borrow or purchase a new power supply and take some solace in a newly upgraded graphics card.

Comment: Yeah I arrived at that conclusion aswell, however what I did was swapped those two six pin outputs from the psu to make sure they still have power coming through them and they run the cards fans either slot that I attach them to. I also attached the adapter that comes with the card to one of the other four pin outputs from the PSU and tried it with the card with no change..

Comment: So you think the PSU could be the issue though I've tried different outputs from it? Would it continue to power other things fine though? Mould the fans still receive power through those outputs? As they move with either of the two 6 pin outputs plugged in.. Sorry if that was confusing.. Can I power the card from another pic while it's plugged into my motherboard ?

Comment: @Rou - Most medium range power supplies have separate lines for the PCI-E power cables, which means those could be damaged, and all other lines could work.  Basically what Mokubai indicated.

Comment: Ahh I see I understand..but would they go totally dead? As mine still omit power as far as I've tested..

Comment: @Rou You say you have tested the six pin connectors. Just how have you tested them?  I have seen other power devices that look like they supply the right voltage until you put it under load at which point they simply collapse. You *might* be able to use a second power supply just for the graphics card but the 0v lines would preferably be tied together between the supplies to ensure that the voltages are referenced correctly. It would be safer to use one supply for the whole system.

Comment: I plugged each six pin into the card to see if it gives power to the cards fans etc and it did seem to at the least run the fans ..however yes if there has been a change to the voltage somehow I'm not sure how to test that. I thought by borrowing a PSU and hooking up the card to that and leaving everything else on the existing PSU as it would be a nightmare to unplug everything

Comment: Ok an update : I have tested the card on another system and it seems to work fine.. So I'm assuming the psu is the issue.. Even though it seems to be running the pc on a whole fine? Strange.. Wandering if I changed something on the system to change the wattage?? You guys know anything about something like that on this PSU http://m.newegg.com/Product/index?itemnumber=N82E16817703022

Comment: As I mentioned your PSU will have multiple independant 12V lines.  If one of them dies then you could have a power supply that can work the majority of your system as you have seen, but your PSU will be unable to fully power the graphics card. It could be that there is enough power to drive the fans but little more. It is sounding more and more that you have a dead power supply.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see.. There was one specific 6 pin with a red dot on it I take it that may have been the 12 v but didn't make much of a difference.. Can't believe I'm gonna have to fork out for a new PSU as well .. Anyone know of any going for cheap?